# display 2 QML files on a single QQuickwidget alternately when required without overlap

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QQuickwidget in a Qt C++ application where i have loaded a QML file (main.qml) and using QAction(actionstart) and C++ functions i have to load another QML file(main1.qml) slightly different to previous one on the same QQuickWidget object.

I am able to do this , but my 2nd QML file is overlapped from the middle section of QQuickwidget and further.

I have did this to stop overlapping of 2 QML files but not successful completely. count3 = 1 is defined in public section of Guiapplication.h file.

```
void GuiApplication::on_actionstart_triggered()
{
if (count3 == 1)
{
  set_animation();
  count3 = 2;
}
}
```

C++ Function for loading 1st QML file(main.qml)

```
void GuiApplication::rolling_animation()
{
QQuickView *quickWidget=new QQuickView();
QWidget *contain = QWidget::createWindowContainer(quickWidget,this);
contain->setMinimumSize(1008,349);
contain->setMaximumSize(1008,349);
contain->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Resources/main.qml"));
ui->horizontalLayout_6->addWidget(contain);
}
```

C++ Function for loading 2nd QML file(main1.qml)

```
void GuiApplication::set_animation()
{
QQuickView *quickWidget=new QQuickView();
QWidget *Contain = QWidget::createWindowContainer(quickWidget,this);
Contain->setMinimumSize(1008,349);
Contain->setMaximumSize(1008,349);
Contain->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Resources/main1.qml"));
ui->horizontalLayout_6->addWidget(Contain);
//ui->horizontalLayout_9->invalidate();
//ui->horizontalLayout_9->removeWidget(quickWidget_4);
}
```

[output window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN2wA.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the results? From the code you posted, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. The `ui->horizontalLayout_6` should arrange the widgets next to each other if it has room (assuming that is a QHBoxLayout). It should not matter what kind of QWidgets you are placing inside (QQuick-related or otherwise). I'm guessing the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to remove one of those widgets first and replace it with the other? If you take a widget out of a layout, you have to specifically hide it or delete it, otherwise it will still be visible, just not in a layout.

Comment: @Max paperno I have added an image of my result. I am not removing any widget. I am using same widget but displaying another qml file on it. I placed QQuickwidget and a spacer in a layout, so that i was able to display my qml file onto quickqidget. I even want to delete or refresh the Qquickwidget after logging out of application, as the QQuickwidget contents are still visible after logging out. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Could anyone help me with the problem. Is it possible using QAction object to load rectangle QML object dynamically with animation (sequential,property, parallel) included after displaying a qml file onto QQuickWidget. Or should i have to use 2nd QML file with animated rectangle objects and display in QQuickWidget.

Comment: Sorry, it is not at all clear to me what you're asking. If the question has changed, you should ask a new question. eyllanesc provided a very comprehensive answer about displaying multiple widgets and switching between them. Your screenshot just looks like there's not enough room to display the two views next to each other, so they overlap. Your example code is probably incomplete, and it is not clear what the `count3` has to do with anything.Any animations in QML files should "just work" when displayed in a QQuickWidget or wherever. I'd like to help but don't know what I'm helping with :)

Comment: @MaxPaperno Thanks for your concern. I will explain from practical point of my application. I am making a GUI application for Hot Rolling Mill. My question is - At first the QQuickwidget displays the animation of Hot rolling Mill without linear translation of the material (steel blocks) (Here Rectangle QML object). On pressing a start icon from QToolbar ,the material should start moving between Roller blocks and split into 2 blocks at shear section and increase speeds according to practical requirement.

Comment: @MaxPaperno  continuation from above comment......... Is it possible to use a single QML file and single QQuickwidget and signal the animation part of QML file dynamically after pressing start icon from QToolbar. My START icon should initiate the material movement dynamically on the QQuickWidget. I hope it is clear now. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Sure, you can interact with loaded QML objects from C++ side if you want. Check https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html for some possibilities. For example you could invoke a QML method which starts the animation. Or set a property value which triggers animation to start. But you need to interact not with the `QQuickWidget/View` itself but with the QML object (file) loaded into it. Like the examples in the docs, you need to get this object after loading into the view with `quickWidget->setSource(...); QObject *qmlObj = quickWidget->rootObject()`.

Comment: I was looking into those documentation pages about invoking QML methods/functions from C++ signals , but QML functions are not accepting rectangle objects or other items and showing syntax problems. My instinct says i can achieve the result by sending C++ signals to qml slots/functions. i have to do something, stuck at the moment. thanks anyway for ur suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to save or not the state of the QML that you want to hide there are the following alternatives:

1. Reject the same QQuickWidget (I recommend changing QQuickView to QQuickWidget) and just change the source.

---

```
#include <QtQuickWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent),
        m_widget(new QQuickWidget)
    {
        m_widget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
        QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("show 1");
        QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("show 2");

        QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout;
        vlay->addWidget(button1);
        vlay->addWidget(button2);
        lay->addLayout(vlay);
        lay->addWidget(m_widget);

        connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::show1);
        connect(button2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::show2);
        show1();
    }
private slots:
    void show1(){
        m_widget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main1.qml"));
    }
    void show2(){
        m_widget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main2.qml"));
    }
private:
    QQuickWidget *m_widget;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

2. Use 2 QuickWidgets and use a QStackedWidget to toggle the widgets, with this method only hidden so the state of the QML will persist, in the previous case when changing the source is lost.

---

```
#include <QtQuickWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent),
        m_stacked_widget(new QStackedWidget)
    {
        for(const QString & url: {"qrc:/main1.qml", "qrc:/main2.qml"}){
            QQuickWidget *widget = new QQuickWidget;
            widget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
            widget->setSource(QUrl(url));
            m_stacked_widget->addWidget(widget);
        }
        QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("show 1");
        QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("show 2");

        QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout;
        vlay->addWidget(button1);
        vlay->addWidget(button2);
        lay->addLayout(vlay);
        lay->addWidget(m_stacked_widget);

        connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::show1);
        connect(button2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::show2);
        show1();
    }
private slots:
    void show1(){
        m_stacked_widget->setCurrentIndex(0);
    }
    void show2(){
        m_stacked_widget->setCurrentIndex(1);
    }
private:
    QStackedWidget *m_stacked_widget;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

The examples can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/54695106)